Visual Studio Code API - is there a way to programmatically change the icon of a folder/file for the "Explorer" pane?
I'm trying to develop a Visual Studio Code extension that will override the icons of certain folders, if said folders contain files that match either a wildcard (e.g. *.csproj) or a full name (e.g. Cargo.toml). The icons would be replaced with the icons that are assigned to the matched files. A good example of this are C# projects, which always have a .csproj file - these folders would get the icon associated with the .csproj extension.
I couldn't find any way to even interact with the Explorer pane - my initial guess was to interact with its TreeView, but this doesn't seem to be possible. Issue #9963 seems to reinforce this belief.
Is there an API (or a hack) that would allow me to change the icon of a specific file/folder that is present in the Explorer window?
